# laravel 5.2 one to many relationship issue

Tags: php, laravel

I setup the following one to many relationship in a Laravel 5.2 model.
There's WorkoutGroup parent model which is referenced in a Workout child model using a group_id attribute. Each WorkoutGroup object can be referenced by several 
Workout oject, hence the one to many relation.

Thing is I can't retrieve the Workout childs from the WorkoutGroup using the workouts method...

Here's the child object

```
// Workout class
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Workout extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'c_workouts';

    protected $fillable = [
        "group_id", "name", "set_time", "created_at", "updated_at"
    ];

    public function group() {
        return $this->belongsTo(WorkoutGroup::class, 'group_id');
    }

}
```

Here's the parent object

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WorkoutGroup extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'c_workouts_groups';

    protected $fillable = [
        "name"
    ];

    public function workouts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Workout::class, 'group_id');
    }
}
```

The migration file

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCWorkoutsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('c_workouts_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', "16");
        });

        DB::table("c_workouts_groups")->insert([
            ["name" => "crunches"],
        ]);

        Schema::create('c_workouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('group_id', false, true)->length(10)->nullable();
            $table->foreign('group_id')
                ->references('id')->on('c_workouts_groups')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('set_time');
            $table->string('name', "128");
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table("c_workouts")->insert([
            ["name" => "bicicleta", "set_time" => 1, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "quadriceps", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "femorales", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "press lombo", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "press pectoral", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "polita alta dorsal", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "biceps", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "triceps", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => null],
            ["name" => "dorsal", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => 1],
            ["name" => "frontal medio alto", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => 1],
            ["name" => "frontal medio bajo", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => 1],
            ["name" => "frontal bajo", "set_time" => 0, "group_id" => 1],
            ["name" => "trotadora", "set_time" => 1, "group_id" => null]
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
        Schema::drop('c_workouts_groups');
        Schema::drop('c_workouts');
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }
}
```

Anybody get what's wrong ?

Comment: Where is your "query/eloquent instruction"?

Comment: I'm doing this  $test = \App\WorkoutGroup::find(1)->first()->workouts();

Comment: Try this: `$test = \App\WorkoutGroup::find(1)->workouts` or `\App\WorkoutGroup::with('workouts')->find(1)`

Comment: That worked Felipe, thanks! What a stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

`$test = \App\WorkoutGroup::find(1)->workouts` lazy loading

or eager loading (usually better) 
`\App\WorkoutGroup::with('workouts')->find(1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `\App\WorkoutGroup::find(1)->workouts` your code should work fine.

When you use `find()`, you don't have a collection, you have a eloquent model, so using `first()` will not have the desire effect.

And when fetching relationships, you do not need to call as a function `->workouts()` If you do that, you have to finalize the query calling the get method `->workouts()->get()`.